# Python class hierarchy dynamic argument before args

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, overriding, class-method

I have two classes

```
class A(Base):
    @classmethod
    def which_active(cls, request: HttpRequest, *variants: str):
        super().which_active(...)     
class B(Base):
    @classmethod
    def which_active(cls, *variants: str):
        super().which_active(...)
```

The logic for both `which_active` methods are very similar and i want to abstract that into a super class like this:

```
class Base:
    @classmethod
    def which_active(cls, x: Any, *variants: str):  
       if cls.is_eligible(x):
          do_this()
       cls.assign(x)
       ....
    @classmethod
    def is_eligible(cls, x:Any):
        ....
    @classmethod
    def assign(cls, x:Any)
        ....
    ....
```

This will cause an error for class B because the signature of the `which_active` method in the base class doesn't match the superclass. How do I design this to use the same method names but different arguments with the possibility of omitting the first argument for the method in the subclasses?

Answer (score 1):

Change `request` to be a named argument, and put it *after* the positional `*variants` argument.

```
@classmethod
def which_active(cls, *variants: str, request: HttpRequest = None):
    if request:
        if cls.is_eligible(request):
            do_this()
        cls.assign(request)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by using *args:

```
I have two classes

class A(Base):
    @classmethod
    def which_active(cls, request: HttpRequest, *variants: str):
        super().which_active(request, *variants)     
class B(Base):
    @classmethod
    def which_active(cls, *variants: str):
        super().which_active(None, *variants)   

class Base:
    @classmethod
    def which_active(cls, request: HttpRequest | None, *variants: str):  
       if cls.is_eligible(request):
          do_this()
       cls.assign(request)
       ....
    @classmethod
    def is_eligible(cls, request: HttpRequest | None):
        ....
    @classmethod
    def assign(cls, request: HttpRequest | None)
        ....
    ....
```

Comment: Dropping a parameter a required parameter (`request`) from `B.which_active` is a violation of the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). If you want `B` to be able to call the method without an explicit `None` argument, you should define a *new* method like `@classmethod def which(cls, *variants: str): return cls.which_active(None, *variants)`.

Comment: (The idea being that, if you have an object of type `Base` but don't know whether it is an `A` or a `B`, you should still be able to call `which_active`. If you have to know the type `A` or `B` ahead of time, you may as well need to know whether to call `which_active` or `which` as well.)